# No active compatible device found to running android application

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I've fully searched this site in order to solve my problem without any success.

My device is Sony Xperia Go (ST27i)

When I want to run my **android application** in Eclipse, I get this error:

> No active compatible AVD's or devices found. Relaunch this
>   configuration after connecting a device or starting an AVD.

But I **can** see my device name in "device list" linked to USB ports.

Can you please help me about this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: check minsdk and maxsdk in manifest file

Comment: @WhoAml I've checked that the installed files for my device already is up to date

Comment: @Vyger You know I've set this values in my app's manifest: android:minSdkVersion="7" and android:targetSdkVersion="17"

Comment: Have you enabled USB debugging on the device? http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

Comment: Yes, the debugging is enabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future readers may have this problem:

I've installed Sony PC Companion and now I can use my phone in order to test the application.

Answer (score 1):

see the

```
 <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="see here"
        android:targetSdkVersion="see here" />
```

for compatibility in your manifest

Comment: The values are: android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="17" (My device OS version is 2.3)

Comment: my minSdkVersion was 8 and targetSdkVersion was 18. I change 8 to 7 and it work. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you connect to your device? Try this from the command line:

```
adb shell
```

If this fails try this as root:

```
killall adb
adb shell
```

Comment: I can connect my device to my computer also I can see my device name in devices list linked to USB ports as "PHONE CARD" with a specified icon

Comment: You have to enable usb debuging in the developer options in the phone settings.

Comment: Fortunately or unfortunately I have enabled that option.

Comment: At least now you know what your problem is. Try my updated answer

Comment: I've tried the first command and this message received: 'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command...